# how to write prefixed unique coupon code in php

Tags: php

I am trying to write prefixed unique coupon code for get the chance to be a intern at one company. It went well so far, my code is generating 250st, 10 length of codes every time I refresh the page. However, I am issuing a problem with prefixed part. Normally coupon code is looking like this, just one example "1SC476XY3B" but I want every code to start "AB" and then 8 length of code so total will be 10. Can you help me guys? All help will be appreciated, thanks.

```
<?php

function unique_coupon_codes($number_of_codes,$exclude_codes_array='',$code_length = 10)
{

$characters = "0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";

$unique_codes = array();
for($j = 1 ; $j <= $number_of_codes; $j++)
{
    $code = "";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $code_length; $i++)
    {
        $code .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
    }

    if(!in_array($code,$unique_codes))
    {
        if(is_array($exclude_codes_array))
        {
            if(!in_array($code,$exclude_codes_array))
            {
                $unique_codes[$j] = $code;
            }
            else
            {
                $j--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $unique_codes[$j] = $code;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $j--;
    }
}
return $unique_codes;
}

echo '<h1>Unique Coupon Codes</h1>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(unique_coupon_codes(250,'',10));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I haven't read the codes yet, but based from the question, since your problem is that every coupon code should starts with **AB**, why not just print **AB** then concatenate the rest of the coupon code?

Comment: I did change it, it worked very well. Thank you @Swellar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs a minor change while initializing `$code` variable. Change `$code = "";` to `$code = "AB";` And call `unique_coupon_codes` function as

```
print_r(unique_coupon_codes(250, '', 8));
```

Here generate a unique code of 8 digits as you already have prefix `AB` of length 2 characters.

Comment: Thank you so much Singh. I only focused to main question that generate 250st code with length of 10digit, that is why I missed it. I did change the code now and worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? :-)

```
function unique_coupon_codes($number_of_codes,$exclude_codes_array=[],$code_length = 10, $code_prefix="") {
   $characters="0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
   $unique_codes = array();
   for($i=1;$i<=$number_of_codes;$i++) {
      $code="";
      for($o=1;$o<=$code_length;$o++) {
         $code .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
      }
      if(in_array($code, $unique_codes) || in_array($code, $exclude_codes_array)) {
         $i--;
      } else {
         $unique_codes[$i] = $code_prefix.$code;
      }
   }
   return $unique_codes;
}

echo '<h1>Unique Coupon Codes</h1>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(unique_coupon_codes(250,'',8, 'AB'));
echo '</pre>';
```